# PHPMailer With Attachment Never Received

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am tying to send an email with an attachment using `phpmailer`.

```
include_once('/home/site/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = $mail->getFile('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.free.fr"; // SMTP server
$mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport

$mail->From       = "name@sub.fr";
$mail->FromName   = "name";

$mail->Subject    = "subject";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress("sub@sub.net", "name");

$mail->AddAttachment("mylist.csv");             // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I receive a "Message sent !" on execution, but no email is ever received.

Comment: Look in your syslog or /var/mail/username to see if any errors or bounce backs have been received.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in the setup. You first specify the use of SMTP and then switch to Sendmail. Which transport are you trying to use?

Comment: Check your spam folder. Email servers have a habit of interpreting automated emails as spam if the headers aren't set up properly.

Comment: Does it send, if you do it without the attachment (AddAttachment may need a path to the file?)

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible the user you sent the email to did not recieve it due to the fact a lot of mail providers such as AOL and Yahoo block massive amounts of Ip addresses related to email spam. So if the server you are running this php script from is on their blacklist the user will not even receive it to the spam folder.

Check your php email logs.

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/php/php-03.html

Also, if this is not the case, try making sure the file your trying to include exists, and you are passing the correct path to the file. Like @Waygood said, try seeing if it sends without the attachment.

Comment: I don't see a errors in syslog and i try to send mail on the ftp.

Comment: i try sends without the attachment but nothing. and for my test i use mymail in laposte.net

Comment: it's ok because I put my script on another server. How can we enable sending email on my server?